# How can you throw 2d objects after dragging them with the mouse, without AddForce?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a small sandbox game for kids where they get to spawn some 2d objects, drag them all over the screen and throw them against each other.

I tried to avoid using AddForce() because the algorithms don't seem to fit my problem (if the kid drags one object in multiple directions, the object trajectory will be quite messy and unrealistic when he releases it).

What I went with instead is to spawn an empty object when you click on an object and attach the two with a HingeJoint2D. It works well when it comes to dragging the object across the screen, but the object just fall flat onto the ground when you release it (the empty object with HingeJoint gets deleted when you release it).

```
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // MousePosition
        Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePos.z = 10;
        Vector3 screenPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !objectInHand)
        {
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(screenPos, Vector2.zero);

            if (hit && hit.collider.tag == "DraggableObject")
            {
                emptyObject = new GameObject("HingeHolder");
                emptyObject.transform.position = screenPos;
                emptyObject.AddComponent<HingeJoint2D>();

                objectInHand = hit.collider.gameObject;

                emptyObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = true;
                emptyObject.GetComponent<HingeJoint2D>().connectedBody = objectInHand.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
                emptyObject.GetComponent<HingeJoint2D>().autoConfigureConnectedAnchor = false;
            }
        }
        else if(Input.GetMouseButton(0) && objetInHand)
        {
            emptyObject.transform.position = screenPos;
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && objetInHand)
        {
            emptyObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic = false;
            emptyObject.GetComponent<HingeJoint2D>().connectedBody = null;
            Destroy(emptyObject);
            objectInHand = null;

        }
    }
```

I would like my object to keep its force on release and to work like AddForce(), but I just can't get it to work properly this way. Am I doing this wrong ? Is this possible without using AddForce() ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you set drag etc you could possibly check the velocity of the mouse with mouse.delta/time.deltatime and set that to the same as the object.

Comment: Try a FixedJoint2D instead of HingeJoint2D.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do what you want is by adding a script to each box:

using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Draggable: MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler {

public float z = 1f;

public void OnDrag(PointerEventData data)
    {

```
    Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
    mousePosition.z = z;
    transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);

}
```

}

this solution prevents us from needing to use the update (improving performance) and you could adjust the mass, gravity, z  and other factors, so that your game.
it would also be good if he had physical limits when his stage is over